# Hive join query returning Cartesian product on inner join

Tags: join, hadoop, hive, cartesian-product, bucket-sort

I am doing inner join on two tables that are created using Hive. One is a big table "**trades_bucket**" and another is a small table "**counterparty_bucket**". They are created as follows :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trades_bucket;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE trades_bucket(
parentId STRING,
BookId STRING) CLUSTERED BY(parentId) SORTED BY(parentId) INTO 32 BUCKETS;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS counterparty_bucket;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE counterparty_bucket(
Version STRING,AccountId STRING,childId STRING) 
CLUSTERED BY(childId ) SORTED BY(childId) INTO 32 BUCKETS;
```

The Join between the tables

```
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(counterparty_bucket) */ BookId , t.counterpartysdsid, c.sds  
FROM counterparty_bucket c join trades_bucket t 
on c.childId = t.parentId
where c.childId ='10001684'
```

The problem is that the join is producing Cartesian product out of the two tables. What I mean is if big table has **100 rows** and small table has **4 rows** for a given id, I expect the join to return **100 rows**, but I am getting back **400 rows**. Anyone have a clue or anyone witnessed similar situation?

Comment: Is your syntax right? Shouldn't you have `MAPJOIN(c)` instead of `MAPJOIN(counterparty)`?

Comment: @SantiagoCepas,It will work irrespective of whether you use alias or the exact table name, Even if I remove the entire MAPJOIN hint, the join always ends up with a Cartesian product.

Comment: But, according to the table definition in your code, the exact table name is `counterparty_bucket` not `counterparty`

Comment: You are right @SantiagoCepas. Its typo. I corrected it.